# I wanna add a gradient to circle(1.7) swiftui

Tags: ios, swiftui

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoginScreen: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                LinearGradient(colors: [.blue, .black], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
                Circle()
                    .scale(1.3)
                    .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.6))
                Circle()
                    .scale(1.7)
                    .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.3))
                
                }
                
                .navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
        }
    }
```

I wanna add a gradient like my background to circle. When I use

```
.background( LinearGradient(colors: [.blue, .black], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
```

its going to all black.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to change the appearance(color, gradient...) of a `Shape`, use `.fill` instead of `.background`.

```
Circle()
    .fill(LinearGradient(colors: [.blue, .black], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
```

Comment: -----Value of type 'some View' has no member 'fill'----- that's the error when I use .fill

Comment: did you use on circle?

Comment: yes I used on circle

Comment: I tried in a clean view and its work but in my code its not.

Comment: You should add it at the top, before any other modifier

Comment: I did then scale gives same error.

Comment: Value of type 'some View' has no member 'scale'